# How to get the near balance and token balance of the contract in near-sdk-rs?

Tags: nearprotocol

I am trying to write AMM, here is my code:

```
pub struct Uniswap {
    uni_totalsupply: u128,
    uni_balance:LookupMap<AccountId, Balance>,

}
impl Uniswap {
        pub fn add_liquidity(&mut self, min_liquidity: u128, max_tokens: u128) {
            let deposit = env::attached_deposit();
            assert!(max_tokens > 0, "Maximum tokens should be greater than zero");
            assert!(deposit > 0, "Deposit must be greater than zero");
            let total_liquidity = self.uni_totalsupply;
            if(total_liquidity > 0) {
                assert!(min_liquidity > 0, "Minimum liquidity must be greater than zero");
                let near_reserve = near_balance_of_contract - deposit;
                let token_reserve = token_balance_of_contract;
        }
    }
 }
```

How to get the near balance of the contract, and token balance of the contract?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are looking for [`env::account_balance`](https://docs.rs/near-sdk/2.0.1/near_sdk/env/fn.account_balance.html)